# Can a Drupal webform be used to create a waitlist registration?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, waitlist

I have a CiviCRM Event which allows waitlist registrations and handles them correctly within Civi - including sending emails when there is a cancellation.

However, a Drupal webform used to enter registrations does not seem to allow/create waitlist registrations.

Is it possible to use the Drupal webform for waitlist registrations?

Comment: What version of CiviCRM and Webform CiviCRM?

Comment: Civi 4.7.26, Drupal 7.57

Comment: Did you ever manage to answer this for yourself?

Comment: FYI - This is still not a thing in CiviCRM 5.28/Drupal 8.9. The webform responds that the event is full (not the waitlist message) and the submission is not saved. The CiviCRM registration waitlist works.

Comment: Ah -> can you please create an issue for D8WFC on the Drupal project page?

Answer (score 1):

I do think that this is possible it also depends on the event configuration in CiviCRM.

If it is not possible you could create a webform in which each participant gets the status on waitlist instead of registered. That way you could create a waitlist.

To enable Participant Status - on waitlist in your webform -> you need to visit: /civicrm/admin/participant_status?reset=1 and enable both `On waitlist` as well as `Pending from waitlist`

Comment: See also [Best Practice for CiviEvent using Webform Integration?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/11257/13) where Karin expands on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use custom code to achieve that. You can use webform, but not civicrm fields in it but regular and use hook_webform_submission_insert which will get fired when webform is submitted and then using API calls, you can add participants in waitlist.

Thanks